# Pi shuts down every day at 11:23 PM

Tags: power, power-supply, crash

I have a Pi Zero W running Raspbian Stretch Lite (June 2018). I'm using it to turn the crank on an automatic cat feeder. I've barely changed the base configuration: apt-get-installed git and samba, used Python's pip to install wiringpi and `psutil`, and scheduled my Python script to run at 7AM and 7PM using `crontab -e`.

In the mornings I've been finding the pi shut down and missed the 7AM feeding. Unplug/replug brings it back up. I set up a ping test from my desktop and discovered for the last three days that the system shuts down at *exactly* 11:23 in the evening (eastern daylight time).

I've confirmed that there is no cron job for the pi user or the super user for that time (or at any time, other than the feedings.) I'm pretty new to Linux. What could be causing this?

Update 2:

I stayed up tonight and observed the issue. Sure enough, the LED switched off at 11:23 and my SSH session went dead. Interesting twist: I powered it up again right away, and it shut down again about 1 minute later! This pattern repeated until around 11:28, after which point it has stayed up no problem.

Here is a gist with the /var/log/messages for the whole affair. What's strange is that the system appears to boot up at 11:17, although I didn't shut it down and my ping test didn't report an outage.

https://gist.github.com/buzzcola/6ea029d7d496d8852b4c7a062945937b

Comment: A bit hard to say.  If you are powering from the mains I'd say something like central heating is switched on at that time which sends an EMF spike and knocks out the Pi.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I was thinking about scheduled tasks in the local software but if it were a power spike it could be anything scheduled in the house. I do have an air conditioner running on a thermostat, but it kicks in based on ambient temperature so the time would be arbitrary.

Comment: I do have a surge suppressor I could plug into. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Any chance your script get stuck in a loop that runs for 4 hrs and 23 minutes before crashing? Power surge is possible, but it seems strange that you'd get one so regularly.

Comment: Does /var/log/syslog show anything around that time?  Is the Pi really "shutdown" like from a `shutdown` command?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I should have been more specific - I said "shut down" but all I mean is that the pi was known to be on at 11:22PM and off at 11:23. Along with being unresponsive to a ping, it doesn't run the cron job to feed the cat, and the green LEDs are out.

Comment: @Brick I'm fairly confident that the script runs quickly and exits correctly - it went through a lot of testing while I fiddled with the hardware. I've also run it from the command line and observed it exiting properly.

Comment: To try: 1. In the comment that you say you posted `/var/log/syslog` but in the edit to the question `/var/log/messages`. Both are interesting, but be clear. 2. The times don't make sense. I was expecting some messages before 23:23 and through 23:28. Is your machine using UK time (the default)?  You said you're EDT. 3. Does your script run properly at 7:00 PM? 4. On the night you stayed up, what happened at 7:00 AM and at 11:23 AM the next day? 5. The logs will all have a *.1 version. Look at that too, it's the previous day. I have root cronjobs that don't appear when I do `sudo crontab -l`.

Comment: @Brick 1. Thanks for the information. I could include "syslog" too if you think it would be helpful. (comment removed to avoid confusion.) 2. I'm in EDT land but my pi is on UTC, so 03:23 (23:23 EDT) is the magic hour of the mysterious shutdown. 3. Assuming I start up the pi after the crash, it runs without error and does both feedings (7AM/7PM) until 11:23 the next evening. 4. At 7AM this morning the feeder worked correctly. It's not yet 11:23AM here but I haven't observed any issues at that time previously. 5. I'll take a look at those logs too, thanks.

Comment: Oh and @joan one further update - for my tests last night the pi was plugged in through a surge suppressor whereas before it was not. The suppressor did not affect the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! It turns out there's another cron file I didn't know about, `/etc/crontab`. I took a look and found this:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
23 3    * * *   pi      python /share/squeakernet/squeakernet.py feed
#
```

The last line was me, I guess. 03:23 (11pm my local time) must have been an incorrect adding of four hours instead of subtracting. When the script runs as the "pi" user (not root) it apparently causes a completely un-logged crash.

Comment: Is there any mechanism that would change /etc/crontab other than directly editing the file? I have no memory of changing this, nor why I would ever have specified 03:23 for the time.

Comment: And how would this explain the repeated crashes from ~11:23 to ~11:28? Does cron pick up missed/failed/recent jobs and try to recover/run them?

Comment: If you do `sudo crontab -e` then you make an entry in root's crontab.  If you do `crontab -e` (without the `sudo`), then you make an entry in the user's crontab, in your case `pi`.  I'd guess that you accidentally did it the wrong way once and didn't notice.  Maybe if you type `history` you'll see it, assuming that it's still in the history.

Comment: Related to some of your secondary questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/609850/what-is-the-correct-way-to-edit-a-crontab-file

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm going to fix my script to check and complain if it's not running with sufficient permissions to use the GPIO. Seems like a better feature than exploding the universe. :)

Comment: If you hadn't found this, I was going to blame the cat next, so just as well that you discovered the answer yourself.